# BeautifulSoup sports scraper gives back empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the results of tennis matches from [this](https://www.flashscore.com/tennis/atp-singles/french-open/results/) website using Python's BeautifulSoup. I have tried a lot of things but I always get back an empty list. Is there an obvious mistake I am making? There are multiple instances of this class on the website when I inspect it, but it does not seem to find it.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/tennis/atp-singles/french-open/results/'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

match_container = soup.find_all('div', class_='event__match event__match--static event__match--last event__match--twoLine')
print(match_container)
```

Comment: Can you try it with selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Results table is loaded via javascript and BeautifulSoup does not find it, because it's not loaded yet at the moment of parsing. To solve this problem you'll need to use selenium. Here is link for [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('<PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER>',chrome_options=chrome_options)

# load page via selenium
wd.get("https://www.flashscore.com/tennis/atp-singles/french-open/results/")

# wait 5 seconds until results table will be loaded
table = WebDriverWait(wd, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'live-table')))

# parse content of the grid
soup = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'lxml')

# access grid cells, your logic should be here
for tag in soup.find_all('div', class_='event__match event__match--static event__match--last event__match--twoLine'):
  print(tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

The score data is pulled into the page dynamically, and you're only getting the initial HTML with requests.

As user70 suggested in the comments, the way to do this is to use a tool like Selenium first so you get all the dynamic content you see in your web browser's inspection tool.

There are few guides online showing how this works - you could start with this one maybe:

https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/web-scraping-using-beautiful-soup-and-selenium-for-dynamic-page-2f8ad15efe25